# Tesseract on very specific large amout of similar images

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a huge dataset of images from which i want to read the text. These data is always in the same form on this images: There are two temperature values, and two velocity value. Here are some examples:

[image: 1]
[image: 5]
[image: 5]
[image: 5]
[image: 5]

the biggest problem i think is that the text is slightly transparent.
I tried to do it with tesseract (pytesseract and tesseract.js) but the results are not really good. Somethings the temperature values are interpreted correct but the velocity values are rarely correct. Especially the point isn't found.

Is there any posiibility to optimize the predictions of tesseract by telling it the pattern of my text, because it ist always the same in every image.

What i already did is congif the whitelist to

```
tessedit_char_whitelist =
```

Do you maybe have any other idea maybe how to preprocces this images best to get better results. I Already tried to increase the contrast. This resulted in a small improvement, but still not particularly good.

Of course i'm also open to any other ocr libraries and programming languages if you think they would work better

Comment: especially the text on the blue background is really hard to segment. Another idea: do you have enough data to train your own OCR model? At least 1000 images, better would be 5000 or more? Including ground truth texts (e.g. "20°C"). If this is possible, you could split each image into 4 images, containing only a single line, and then feed each of these lines into the model. You can then even train the model to directly recognize the text without further preprocessing, i.e. it learns to ignore the background. And yes, also constrained decoding (e.g. by using regex to limit output) is possible.

Comment: I've already thought about training my own ocr model. I have defentily enought images for this, but the probelem for this is that i would have to copy 1000 - 5000 (as you said) by hand. So this would maybe be a last option for me.

Comment: what do you mean by "copy"? Annotate, i.e. assigning the ground truth text like "20°C"?

Comment: By copy i mean i have to write the values of about 1000 - 5000 images by hand, by myself. Sounds like a couple of days work to me ;)